# asp.net core MVC static file given 404 error when run website from parent directory

Tags: asp.net-core, command-line-interface

I have an incomprehensible bug recently.

I published a ASP.NET Core MVC web application to a folder, 
when I enter the root path of the website and run it using command

```
d:\publish> dotnet WebSite.dll
```

all things works fine.

but when I go to the parent folder of this website, and then use below command to run it.

```
d:\> dotnet ./publish/WebSite.dll
```

the web site can visit,but all the static files given a 404 error[image],

I want to know, why? how can I solve this?

Comment: It seem read a wrong file path, when I display the ContentRootPath, It's show the current run command path, D:\.

Comment: It's likely due to the paths you used. In Razor code you use the `~/` path prefix to specify that it should be relative to the document root. If you use just `/` at the beginning of your paths, then that will be *domain* relative, which may or may not be the same thing. Bear in mind that `~/` is non-standard, though, so it only works in things like Razor views, as Razor will extrapolate that for you. If you're referencing paths in something like a JS file, you'll need a different solution.

Comment: It seems the root path of app.UseStaticFiles using is depend on  env.ContentRootPath, because env.ContentRootPath take path where you run the command. so the physical path is getting wrong, I will give out the solution for this case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Because `UseStaticFiles` use the path from `env.ContentRootPath`, But `env.ContentRootPath` will take path where you run the `dotnet` command, so the physical path is getting wrong.

I have reassign the base physical path like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}/wwwroot")
});
```

And all static resources are revisited.